# Presentation of $\mathbb{Z}_9\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_3$ (Semi direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_9$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want Presentation of $\mathbb{Z}_9\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_3$  which is semi direct product of  $\mathbb{Z}_9 $ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$. My first guess is as below

$$\mathbb{Z}_9\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_3= \{a,b:a^9=b^3=e, bab^{-1}=a^4\}.$$ Which i tried by using GAP just by looking at elements.

Please tell me is it right or not. Thanks.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown its just my guess....how can i verify it???

Comment: Well, there are only a few options for an automorphism of order $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semidirect products of cyclic groups $C_n$ by $C_m$, i.e. $C_n \rtimes C_m$ have the presentation
$$
\langle x,y∣x^n=y^m=1,y^{-1}xy=\phi(y)^{-1}xφ(y) \rangle,
$$
where $φ:C_m→U(n)$ is the chosen homomorphism, and $y$ generates $C_m$. The proof can be found on this site.

Comment: Which site?..................

Comment: This site: https://math.stackexchange.com, where you are posting your question. It is easy to prove if you know that $U(n)$ has order $\phi(n)$, and the use the remark of Tobias to look for $\phi$.

Comment: okkk ....Then my presentation is ok ???

Comment: Yes, check it with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product), under "Examples".

Comment: Thanks............